# How to get the latest value emited from observable

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

Suppose, i have a timer which emits one item after one second interval.

I want to subscribe to it and execute it for 10 seconds. After 10 seconds i unsubscribe from it and then i want to be able to have access to its last emmited value from some other part of the code.
Here is sample code:

```
@Test
fun testMeasuretime(){

    val emitter = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .doOnNext{t: Long? -> Log.v("emitter", t.toString())}

    val disposable = emitter.subscribe()
    Thread.sleep(10000)

    disposable.dispose()

    Thread.sleep(5000)

//get the last emited value

    Thread.sleep(5000)

}
```

Is there a way to get the last emited value from ohter part of the code?
I want to use this solution to just measure time execution of some task.

Comment: What is this other part? Why not just use `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the start and the end of your measurement?

Comment: It is not in the same scope of the function that started measurement, it can be in the other thread as well or callback. But maybe this is good idea that you are proposing.

Comment: You need another variable/field to save the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the last value by either using `doOnNext()` to set the value of a class field, or inserting a `BehaviorSubject` in the path.

However, I don't think your code is actually measuring the CPU time of execution of the task. Instead, it is capturing the start and end points of processing on possibly an unrelated thread. So, the best you can get is the wall-clock time.

A better approach is something like (written in Java, since I don't know Kotlin):

```
long start = System.nanoTime();
performTaskOnThisThread();
long end = System.nanoTime();
long durationInNanoSeconds = end - start;
```